# Object properties with special characters in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

I am writing a website where I have a language file looking like the following:

```
replace = {
    "x:a": "Hello",
    "x:b": "World!",
    "y:c.d": "Another text"
}
```

And now I want to pass this object to my express page (which is using EJS) to replace the template placeholders:

app.js

```
res.render('index.ejs', replace)
```

index.ejs

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <%= x:a %>
         <%= x:b %>
         <%= y:c.d %>
    </body>
</html>
```

But obviously this isn't working, because x:a is not a valid name, so how can I call these names in my index.ejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an object instead, then access properties on it.

```
res.render('index.ejs', { replace })
```

---

```
     <%= replace['x:a'] %>
     <%= replace['x:b'] %>
     <%= replace['y:c.d'] %>
```